# Find all decorated functions in a module

Tags: python

Is it possible to find out if a function is decorated at runtime? For example could I find all functions in a module that are decorated by "example"?

```
@example
def test1():
    print "test1"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the general case it is not possible because the `example` decorator might not leave any trace that's detectable at runtime -- for example, it **could** be

```
def example(f):
  return f
```

If you do control the source for `example`, it's of course easy to make it mark or record the functions it's decorating; if you don't, it may be utterly impossible to do what you want.

Answer (score 14):

Since you have indicated that you have the control over the wrapper code, here is an example:

```
def example(f):
    f.wrapped = True
    return f

@example
def test1():
    print "test1"

def test2():
    print "test2"


print test1.wrapped
print hasattr(test2, 'wrapped')
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a general way since a decorator is a simple function call. Your code is identical to this:

```
def test1():
    print "test1"

test1 = example(test1)
```

You could probably detect specific decorators by disassembling and analysing (using the `dis` module). Or you could simply parse the source file, though that's a bit ugly.

Why do you want to detect them in the first place?

Comment: My script is used to access a RESTful interface. I wanted to introspect my module and find all the methods "marked" with a certain decorator and build my "optparse" options at runtime. Since the decorator enforces some consistency for my arguments, it made sense to check against that as all of the REST endpoints would be decorated by it.

Comment: If you could edit some sample code from the decorated module and the definition of the decorator, we could probably figure a way to do that.

Comment: I can actually easily achieve what I want if I simply prefixed my "optparse"-able functions with "do_" or something like that. Then I can loop through the functions and create an optparse option for functions that start with "do_". I just felt it would be cleaner to check based on my decorator.

Comment: If you're the one writing the decorator, you can make it add the function to a module-level variable (then return it) and simply read the variable in the client code.

Comment: I don't believe the `dis` modules will help, but I also thought of parsing the sourcecode. The downside is that it only gives you a name and not a reference (though you could put the name through `globals()` if all your decorators are in your module namespace). It may be a year late, but if anyone is still interested, it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5910703/711085

Answer (score 2):

You may find this recent question provides detailed information on 3 ways to do this:

[Howto get all methods of a python class with given decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5910703/711085)

Answer (score -1):

If you can, monkeypatch the decorator at runtime to catch which functions are being passed to it:

```
decfuncs = []

def decpatch(dec):
  def catchdec(func, *args, **kwargs):
    decfuncs.append(func)
    return dec(func, *args, **kwargs)
  return catchdec

somemodule.somedecorator = decpatch(somemodule.somedecorator)
```