# Get Python function's owning class from decorator

Tags: python, class, function, decorator, inspect

I have a decorator in PY.  It is a method and takes the function as a parameter.  I want to create a directory structure based based on the passed function.  I am using the module name for the parent directory but would like to use the classname for a subdirectory.  I can't figure out how to get the name of the class that owns the fn object.

My Decorator:

```
def specialTest(fn):
    filename = fn.__name__
    directory = fn.__module__
    subdirectory = fn.__class__.__name__ #WHERE DO I GET THIS
```

Comment: give a special argument in the decorator saying `is_member_func`, if it is true get the first argument which is self.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `fn` is an `instancemethod`, then you can use `fn.im_class`.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
...
>>> Foo.bar.im_class
__main__.Foo
```

Note that this will *not* work from a decorator, because a function is only transformed into an instance method *after* the class is defined (ie, if `@specialTest` was used to decorate `bar`, it would not work; if it's even possible, doing it at that point would have to be done by inspecting the call stack or something equally unhappy).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks.

Comment: For some reason this didn't register until I went back into the code.  This is possible, I simply have to move my code that interacts with the FN inside the wrapped function, where FN is an instance.

Comment: That's not possible at definition time, however you can list decorated functions after the class was created: to achieve this, the decorator must place some marker attribute on the class

Comment: @kolypto do you mean a marker attribute on the _wrapped function_ ...since the problem so far is the decorator can't access the class?

Comment: @Anentropic, right: some code must post-process methods on the created class, and to tell which methods were decorated -- we need to mark them somehow. For instance, with a custom attribute

Answer (score 7):

In Python 2 you can use `im_class` attribute on the method object. In Python 3, it'll be `__self__.__class__` (or `type(method.__self__)`).

Answer (score 1):

### Getting the Class Name

If all you want is the class name (and not the class itself), it's available as part of the function's (partially) [qualified name attribute](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/) (`__qualname__`).

```
import os.path

def decorator(fn):
    filename = fn.__name__
    directory = fn.__module__
    subdirectory = fn.__qualname__.removesuffix('.' + fn.__name__).replace('.', os.path.sep)
    return fn

class A(object):
    @decorator
    def method(self):
        pass
    
    class B(object):
        @decorator
        def method(self):
            pass
```

If the method's class is an inner class, the qualname will include the outer classes. The above code handles this by replacing all dot separators with the local path separator.

Nothing of the class beyond its name is accessible when the decorator is called as the class itself is not yet defined.

### Getting the Class At Method Call

If the class itself is needed and access can be delayed until the decorated method is (first) called, the decorator can wrap the function, as per usual, and the wrapper can then access the instance and class. The wrapper can also remove itself and undecorate the method if it should only be invoked once.

```
import types

def once(fn):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something with the class
        subdirectory = type(self).__name__
        ...
        # undecorate the method (i.e. remove the wrapper)
        setattr(self, fn.__name__, types.MethodType(fn, self))
        
        # invoke the method
        return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class A(object):
    @once
    def method(self):
        pass

a = A()
a.method()
a.method()
```

Note that this will only work if the method is called.

### Getting the Class After Class Definition

If you need to get the class info even if the decorated method is not called, you can store a reference to the [decorator on the wrapper (method #3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5910893/90527), then scan the methods of all classes (after the classes of interest are defined) for those that refer to the decorator:

```
def decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__decorator__ = decorator
    wrapper.__name__ = 'decorator + ' + fn.__name__
    wrapper.__qualname__ = 'decorator + ' + fn.__qualname__
    return wrapper

def methodsDecoratedBy(cls, decorator):
    for method in cls.__dict__.values():
        if     hasattr(method, '__decorator__') \
           and method.__decorator__ == decorator:
            yield method

#...
import sys, inspect

def allMethodsDecoratedBy(decorator)
    for name, cls in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules, lambda x: inspect.isclass(x)):
        for method in methodsDecoratedBy(cls, decorator):
            yield method
```

This basically makes the decorator an annotation in the general programming sense (and not the sense of [function annotations in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), which are only for function arguments and the return value). One issue is the decorator must be the last applied, otherwise the class attribute won't store the relevant wrapper but another, outer wrapper. This can be dealt with in part by storing (and later checking) all decorators on the wrapper:

```
def decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__decorator__ = decorator
    if not hasattr(fn, '__decorators__'):
        if hasattr(fn, '__decorator__'):
            fn.__decorators__ = [fn.__decorator__]
        else:
            fn.__decorators__ = []
    wrapper.__decorators__ = [decorator] + fn.__decorators__
    wrapper.__name__ = 'decorator(' + fn.__name__ + ')'
    wrapper.__qualname__ = 'decorator(' + fn.__qualname__ + ')'
    return wrapper

def methodsDecoratedBy(cls, decorator):
    for method in cls.__dict__.values():
        if hasattr(method, '__decorators__') and decorator in method.__decorators__:
            yield method
```

Additionally, any decorators you don't control can be made to cooperate by decorating them so they will store themselves on their wrappers, just as `decorator` does:

```
def bind(*values, **kwvalues):
    def wrap(fn):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal kwvalues
            kwvalues = kwvalues.copy()
            kwvalues.update(kwargs)
            return fn(self, *values, *args, **kwvalues)
        wrapper.__qualname__ = 'bind.wrapper'
        return wrapper
    wrap.__qualname__ = 'bind.wrap'
    return wrap

def registering_decorator(decorator):
    def wrap(fn):
        decorated = decorator(fn)
        decorated.__decorator__ = decorator
        if not hasattr(fn, '__decorators__'):
            if hasattr(fn, '__decorator__'):
                fn.__decorators__ = [fn.__decorator__]
            else:
                fn.__decorators__ = []
        if not hasattr(decorated, '__decorators__'):
            decorated.__decorators__ = fn.__decorators__.copy()
        decorated.__decorators__.insert(0, decorator)
        decorated.__name__ = 'reg_' + decorator.__name__ + '(' + fn.__name__ + ')'
        decorated.__qualname__ = decorator.__qualname__ + '(' + fn.__qualname__ + ')'
        return decorated
    wrap.__qualname__ = 'registering_decorator.wrap'
    return wrap

class A(object):
    @decorator
    def decorated(self):
        pass
    
    @bind(1)
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b
    
    @registering_decorator(bind(1))
    @decorator
    def args(self, *args):
        return args
    
    @decorator
    @registering_decorator(bind(a=1))
    def kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        return kwargs

A.args.__decorators__
A.kwargs.__decorators__
assert not hasattr(A.add, '__decorators__')
a = A()
a.add(2)
# 3
```

Another problem is scanning all classes is inefficient. You can make this more efficient by using an additional class decorator to register all classes to check for the method decorator. However, this approach is brittle; if you forget to decorate the class, it won't be recorded in the registry.

```
class ClassRegistry(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.registry = {}
    
    def __call__(self, cls):
        self.registry[cls] = cls
        cls.__decorator__ = self
        return cls
    
    def getRegisteredClasses(self):
        return self.registry.values()

class DecoratedClassRegistry(ClassRegistry):
    def __init__(self, decorator):
        self.decorator = decorator
        super().__init__()
    
    def isDecorated(self, method):
        return (    hasattr(method, '__decorators__') \
                and self.decorator in method.__decorators__) \
            or (    hasattr(method, '__decorator__') \
                and method.__decorator__ == self.decorator)
    
    def getDecoratedMethodsOf(self, cls):
        if cls in self.registry:
            for method in cls.__dict__.values():
                if self.isDecorated(method):
                    yield method
    
    def getAllDecoratedMethods(self):
        for cls in self.getRegisteredClasses():
            for method in self.getDecoratedMethodsOf(cls):
                yield method
```

Usage:

```
decoratedRegistry = DecoratedClassRegistry(decorator)

@decoratedRegistry
class A(object):
    @decoratedRegistry
    class B(object):
        @decorator
        def decorated(self):
            pass
        
        def func(self):
            pass
    
    @decorator
    def decorated(self):
        pass
    
    @bind(1)
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b
    
    @registering_decorator(bind(1))
    @decorator
    def args(self, *args):
        return args
    
    @decorator
    @registering_decorator(bind(a=1))
    def kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        return kwargs

decoratedRegistry.getRegisteredClasses()
list(decoratedRegistry.getDecoratedMethodsOf(A.B))
list(decoratedRegistry.getDecoratedMethodsOf(A))
list(decoratedRegistry.getAllDecoratedMethods())
```

Monitoring multiple decorators and applying multiple decorator registries left as exercises.