# Python class method decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I write a decorator for class method

```
def decor(method):
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # [*]
    return wrapped
```

I would like use this like:

```
class A(metaclass=mymetaclass):
    @decor
    def meth(self):
        pass
```

How I can in decorator add method/variable to class which has decorated method? I need it do near `[*]`.
Inside wrapped I could write `self.__class__`, but what to do here?

Comment: You can use `method.im_class` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680446/get-python-functions-owning-class-from-decorator

Comment: You didn't really care about it being an actual @classmethod right? Reading your question it doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot imagine a way to meet such a requirement, because `decor` function only receives a function object that knows nothing about a containing class.

The only workaround that I can imagine is to use a parameterized decorator and pass it the class being decorated

```
def decor(cls):
    def wrapper(method):
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.method(*args, **kwargs)
        print method   # only a function object here
        return wrapped
    print cls  # here we get the class and can manipulate it
    return wrapper

class A
    @decor(A)
    def method(self):
        pass
```

Alternatively, you could decorate the class itself:

```
def cdecor(cls):
    print 'Decorating', cls  # here we get the class and can manipulate it
    return cls

@cdecor
class B:
    def meth(self):
        pass
```

gives:

```
Decorating __main__.B
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just wanted to decorate one of a classes functions, not specifically an @classmethod. Here's a simple way that I did it when I wanted to call a classes save function when the function returned a successful result:

```
def save_on_success(func):
    """ A decorator that calls a class object's save method when successful """
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if result:
            self.save()
        return result
    return inner
```

Here is an example of how it was used:

```
class Test:
    def save(self):
            print('saving')
    @save_on_success
    def test(self, var, result=True):
            print('testing, var={}'.format(var))
            return result
```

Testing to make sure it works as expected:

```
>>> x = Test()
>>> print(x.test('test True (should save)', result=True))
testing, var=test True (should save)
saving
True
>>> print(x.test('test False (should not save)', result=False))
testing, var=test False (should not save)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not directly possible, according to this response :

[Get Python function's owning class from decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680446/get-python-functions-owning-class-from-decorator)

What you could do instead is providing a decorator for your class, something like that :

```
class InsertMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, methodToInsert):
        self.methodToInsert = methodToInsert

    def __call__(self, classObject):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            setattr(classObject, self.methodToInsert.__name__, self.methodToInsert)
            return classObject(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

def IWillBeInserted(self):
    print "Success"


@InsertMethod(IWillBeInserted)
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def action(self):
        self.IWillBeInserted()


a = Something()
a.action()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you may decorate the class itself:

```
def class_decorator(class_):
    class_.attribute = 'value'
    class_.method = decorate(class_.method)
    return class_

@class_decorator
class MyClass:
    def method(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but late is better than never eh? :)

We can do this by decorating our class method with a decorator which is itself a class object, say `B`, and then hook into the moment when Python calls `B.__get__` so to fetch the method. In that `__get__` call, which will be passed both the owner class and the newly generated instance of that class, you can elect to either insert your method/variable into the original owner class, or into the newly defined instance.

```py
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):

        instance.inserted = True
        # owner.inserted = True
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return self(instance, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

class A:
    @B
    def method(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    a.method()
    b = A()

    print(hasattr(a, 'inserted'))
    print(hasattr(b, 'inserted'))
```

In this example, we're wrapping `def method(self)` with `@B`. As written, the inserted attribute `inserted` will only persist in the `a` object because it's being applied to the instance. If we were to create a second object `b` as shown, the `inserted` attribute is not included. IE, `hasattr(a, 'inserted')` prints `True` and `hasattr(b, 'inserted')` prints `False`. If however we apply `inserted` to the `owner` class (as shown in the commented out line) instead, the inserted attribute will persist into all future `A()` objects. IE `hasattr(a, 'inserted')` prints `True` and `hasattr(b, 'inserted')` prints `True`, because `b` was created after `a.method()` was called.