# Lookup @property methods with inspect module

Tags: python

Is there a way to programmatically lookup the names of all `@property` decorated methods in a class using the `inspect` module?

Comment: This appears to be the first question of its kind? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%40cached_property+inspect

Comment: I've scoured the web and the docs and I do not see a way to do it.

Comment: I wager that @AlexMartelli will get first post.

Comment: While I don't think there's an `inspect` function to do this automatically, you could quite easily write your own code iterating over the class's attributes: `[name for name, obj in vars(some_class).items() if isinstance(obj, property)]`. This might not work for other decorators though, if they don't create objects of some easy to recognize type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My version:

```
import inspect


class A(object):
    @property 
    def name():
        return "Masnun"


def method_with_property(klass):
    props = []

    for x in inspect.getmembers(klass):

        if isinstance(x[1], property):
            props.append(x[0])

    return props

print method_with_property(A)
```

Another version from another thread:

```
import inspect

def methodsWithDecorator(cls, decoratorName):
    sourcelines = inspect.getsourcelines(cls)[0]
    for i,line in enumerate(sourcelines):
        line = line.strip()
        if line.split('(')[0].strip() == '@'+decoratorName: # leaving a bit out
            nextLine = sourcelines[i+1]
            name = nextLine.split('def')[1].split('(')[0].strip()
            yield(name)

class A(object):
    @property 
    def name():
        return "Masnun"



print list(methodsWithDecorator(A, 'property'))
```

The code of `methodsWithDecorator` is taken from the accepted answer on this thread: [Howto get all methods of a python class with given decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910703/howto-get-all-methods-of-a-python-class-with-given-decorator)